# Is shared memory array returned by CreateFileMapping/MapViewOfFile zero initialized?

Tags: c++, winapi, shared-memory

Just curious if I'm creating a shared memory array on Windows platform like so:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE | SEC_COMMIT, 0, 1024 * 4, _T("mySharedMemName"));
if(hFile)
{
    VOID* pData = MapViewOfFile(hFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 1024 * 4);

    //Is 'pData' array initialized with zeros the first time the 'hFile' is used?
}
```

Is the memory array initialized with 0's the first time I call this code snippet? And if no, how to make it zero initialized?

Comment: Most operating systems zero fill all pages that are newly mapped into the address space of a process (unless those pages are shared or backed by disk files or peripheral devices). Not doing so would be unwise from security point of view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The initial contents of the pages in a file mapping object backed by the operating system paging file are 0 (zero).

Comment: Thanks. Evidently I missed it. It's nice that we don't have to clear it.